# Connecting a Hyper-V Virtual Switch to an External network that's a TAP driver

Tags: network-adapter, hyper-v

What I want to do is have WiFi > Freedome (VPN) > vEthernet > Virtual Machine, so all guest traffic goes through the Freedome VPN on my host.

In Hyper-V, I can create a new Virtual Switch, and set the Connection type to External network, with the Freedome TAP driver. I select "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter".

I have to go into Network Connections, and re-enable Internet Protocol Version 4/6 on the Freedome TAP driver (as this gets disabled), otherwise Freedome won't connect. This works fine on my host machine.

When Freedome has connected, the new virtual switch shows as connected to an Unidentified network. When I run diagnose on this connection, I get an error that vEthernet doesn't have a valid IP configuration.

Is it possible to have a vEthernet use a network connection that is a TAP driver?